# Error while merging dex archives: Program type already present: org.apache.commons.io.Charsets

Tags: java, android, react-native

I'm trying to release APK in react native using `./gradlew bundleRelease` I tried

- Cleaning gradle
- Adding multiDexEnabled true

> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - What went wrong: Execution failed for task ':app:transformDexArchiveWithDexMergerForRelease'.
>   com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException:
>   com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Error while
>   merging dex archives:   Program type already present:
>   org.apache.commons.io.Charsets   Learn how to resolve the issue at
>   https://developer.android.com/studio/build/dependencies#duplicate_classes.

This is my build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        buildToolsVersion = "28.0.3"
        minSdkVersion = 23
        compileSdkVersion = 28
        targetSdkVersion = 28
        supportLibVersion = "28.0.0"
        googlePlayServicesVersion = "11+"
    }
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.2'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.3'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenLocal()
        jcenter()
        maven {
            // All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) is installed from npm
            url "$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android"
        }
        maven {
            // Android JSC is installed from npm
            url("$rootDir/../node_modules/jsc-android/dist")
        }
    }
}
```

app/build.gradle

```
apply plugin: "com.android.application"

import com.android.build.OutputFile



project.ext.react = [
    entryFile: "index.js",
    enableHermes: false
]

apply from: '../../node_modules/react-native-unimodules/gradle.groovy'
apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native/react.gradle"

/**
 * Set this to true to create two separate APKs instead of one:
 *   - An APK that only works on ARM devices
 *   - An APK that only works on x86 devices
 * The advantage is the size of the APK is reduced by about 4MB.
 * Upload all the APKs to the Play Store and people will download
 * the correct one based on the CPU architecture of their device.
 */
def enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture = false

/**
 * Run Proguard to shrink the Java bytecode in release builds.
 */
def enableProguardInReleaseBuilds = false

android {
    compileSdkVersion rootProject.ext.compileSdkVersion
    buildToolsVersion rootProject.ext.buildToolsVersion

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.package..."
        minSdkVersion 23
        targetSdkVersion rootProject.ext.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode 33
        versionName "33.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    splits {
        abi {
            reset()
            enable enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture
            universalApk false  // If true, also generate a universal APK
            include "armeabi-v7a", "x86", "arm64-v8a", "x86_64"
        }
    }
    signingConfigs {
        release {
            if (project.hasProperty('MYAPP_UPLOAD_STORE_FILE')) {
                storeFile file(MYAPP_UPLOAD_STORE_FILE)
                storePassword MYAPP_UPLOAD_STORE_PASSWORD
                keyAlias MYAPP_UPLOAD_KEY_ALIAS
                keyPassword MYAPP_UPLOAD_KEY_PASSWORD
            }
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled enableProguardInReleaseBuilds
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro"
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
    }
    // applicationVariants are e.g. debug, release
    applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        variant.outputs.each { output ->
            // For each separate APK per architecture, set a unique version code as described here:
            // http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide/apk-splits
            def versionCodes = ["armeabi-v7a":1, "x86":2, "arm64-v8a": 3, "x86_64": 4]
            def abi = output.getFilter(OutputFile.ABI)
            if (abi != null) {  // null for the universal-debug, universal-release variants
                output.versionCodeOverride =
                        versionCodes.get(abi) * 1048576 + defaultConfig.versionCode
            }
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }


    packagingOptions {
       pickFirst '**/libjsc.so'
       pickFirst 'lib/x86/libc++_shared.so'
       pickFirst 'lib/x86_64/libjsc.so'
       pickFirst 'lib/arm64-v8a/libjsc.so'
       pickFirst 'lib/arm64-v8a/libc++_shared.so'
       pickFirst 'lib/x86_64/libc++_shared.so'
       pickFirst 'lib/armeabi-v7a/libc++_shared.so'  
    }

    
}

def jscFlavor = 'org.webkit:android-jsc:+'

def enableHermes = project.ext.react.get("enableHermes", false);

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    implementation "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:${rootProject.ext.supportLibVersion}"
    implementation "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"  // From node_modules
    implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:17.0.0"
    implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:17.0.0"

    //Add these lines
    implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:17.3.0"
    //implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-core:15.0.2"
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:20.2.1"
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-inappmessaging:19.0.7"
    // implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-inappmessaging-display:19.0.7"
    //implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
    //implementation project(':@mauron85_react-native-background-geolocation')
    
    
    addUnimodulesDependencies()

    if (enableHermes) {
        def hermesPath = "../../node_modules/hermes-engine/android/";
        debugImplementation files(hermesPath + "hermes-debug.aar")
        releaseImplementation files(hermesPath + "hermes-release.aar")
    } else {
        implementation jscFlavor
    }


}

// Run this once to be able to run the application with BUCK
// puts all compile dependencies into folder libs for BUCK to use
task copyDownloadableDepsToLibs(type: Copy) {
    from configurations.compile
    into 'libs'
}

apply from: file("../../node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-android/native_modules.gradle");
applyNativeModulesAppBuildGradle(project)

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Still failing but on my emulator and android device its working fine. Does anyone have this problem too? I really appreciate any idea thanks.